# Can someone help me point my cql shell to my apache database

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

Can someone help me point my `cql shell` to my `apache` database instead of my `localhost`?  I need to be able to change it with the `cql shell` at the `cqlsh` prompt.  I have the address.

Answer (score 0):

Give the DataStax [CQLSH documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html) a read.  Basically, just add your IP address as a parameter on the `cqlsh` command like this:

```
$ bin/cqlsh 192.168.23.109
```

Although, if you installed Cassandra using `apt-get` (or another Linux package manager) you shouldn't need to preface `cqlsh` with `bin/` like I did above.

If you are one of the unfortunate few who are trying to run Cassandra on Windows, then you'll need to modify the **target** of your cqlsh shortcut similar to this:

```
"C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh" 192.168.23.109
```

Note that the IP address is *outside* of the double quotes.